# What would be the best (runtime performance) application or pattern or code or library for matching string patterns

Tags: regex, string, file, pattern-matching, match

I have been trying to figure out a decent way of matching string patterns.  I will try my best to provide as much information as I can regarding what I am trying to do.

The simplest thougt is that there are some specified patterns and we want to know which of these patterns match completely or partially to a given request.  The specified patterns hardly change.  The amount of requests are about 10K per day but the results have to pe provided ASAP and thus runtime performance is the highest priority.

I have been thinking of using Assembly Compiled Regular Expression in C# for this, but I am not sure if I am headed in the right direction.

Scenario:
Data File:
  Let's assume that data is provided as an XML request in a known schema format.  It has anywehere between 5-20 rows of data.  Each row has 10-30 columns. Each of the columns also can only have data in a pre-defined pattern.  For example:

1. A1- Will be "3 digits" followed by a
   "." follwed by "2 digits" -
   [0-9]{3}.[0-9]{2}
2. A2- Will be "1
   character" follwoed by "digits" -
   [A-Z][0-9]{4}

   The sample would be something like:

> ```
> <Data>  
>   <R1>  
>     <A1>123.45</A1>  
>     <A2>A5567</A2>  
>     <A4>456EV</A4>  
>     <An>xxx</An>  
>   </R1>
> </Data>
> ```

Rule File:

```
Rule ID    A1                 A2       
1001       [0-9]{3}.45        A55[0-8]{2}  
2002       12[0-9].55         [X-Z][0-9]{4}   
3055       [0-9]{3}.45        [X-Z][0-9]{4}
```

Rule Location - I am planning to store the Rule IDs in some sort of bit mask.
So the rule IDs are then listed as location on a string

```
Rule ID     Location (from left to right)  
1001            1   
2002            2  
3055            3
```

Pattern file:  (This is not the final structure, but just a thought)

```
Column   Pattern                Rule Location
A1       [0-9]{3}.45            101
A1       12[0-9].55             010 
A2       A55[0-8]{2}            100
A2       [X-Z][0-9]{4}          011
```

Now let's assume that **SOMEHOW** (not sure how I am going to limit the search to save time) I run the regex and make sure that A1 column is only matched aginst A1 patterns and A2 column against A2 patterns. I would end up with the follwoing reults for "Rule Location"

```
Column   Pattern                Rule Location
A1       [0-9]{3}.45            101
A2       A55[0-8]{2}            100
```

- Doing AND on each of the loctions
  gives me the location 1 - 1001 -
  Complete match.
- Doing XOR on each of the loctions
  gives me the location 3 - 3055 -
  Partial match.  (I am purposely not
  doing an OR, because that would have
  returned 1001 and 3055 as the result
  which would be wrong for partial
  match)

The final reulsts I am looking for are:
1001 - Complete Match
3055 - Partial Match

**Start Edit_1:  Explanation on Matching results**

- Complete Match - This occurs when all
  of the patterns in given Rule are
  matched.
- Partial Match - This ocurrs when NOT
  all of the patterns in given Rule are
  matched, but atleast one pattern
  matches.

  Example Complete Match (AND):
  Rule ID 1001 matched for A1(101) and A2 (100).  If you look at the first charcter in 101 and 100 it is "1".  When you do an AND - 1 AND 1 the result is 1.  Thus position 1 i.e. 1001 is a Complete Match.

  Exmple Partial Match (XOR):
  Rule ID 3055 matched for A1(101).  If you look at the last character in 101 and 100 it is "1" and "0".  When you do an XOR - 1 XOR 0 the result is 1.  Thus position 3 i.e. 3055 is Partial Match.
  **End Edit_1**

Input:
The data will be provided in some sort of XML request.  It can be one big request with 100K Data nodes or 100K requests with one data node only.
Rules:
The matching values have to be intially saved as some sort of pattern to make it easier to write and edit.  Let's assume that there are approximately 100K rules.

Output:
Need to know which rules matched completely and partially.

Preferences:
I would prefer doing as much of the coding as I can in C#.  However if there is a major performance boost, I can use a different language.

The "Input" and "Output" are my requirements, how I manage to get the "Output" does not matter.  It has to be fast, lets say each Data node has to be processed in approximately 1 second.

Questions:

1. Are there any existing pattern or
   framewroks to do this?
2. Is using Regex the right path
   specifically Assembly Compiled
   Regex?
3. If I end up using Regex how can I
   specify for A1 patterns to only
   match against A1 column?
4. If I do specify rule locations in a
   bit type pattern.  How do I process
   ANDs and XORs when it grows to be
   100K charcter long?

I am looking for any suggestions or options that I should consider.

Thanks..

Comment: Your AND and XOR explanation for complete and partial matches is unclear.  I am also not sure what you mean by a partial match.

Comment: I have provided additional explanation on AND, XOR, Complete Match and Partial match in the main request.  Please look at section marked Edit_1.  Sorry I was not clear from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression API only tells you when they fully matched, not when they partially matched.  What you therefore need is some variation on a regular expression API that lets you try to match multiple regular expressions at once, and at the end can tell you which matched fully, and which partially matched.  Ideally one that lets you precompile a set of patterns so you can avoid compilation at runtime.

If you had that then you could match your A1 patterns against the AI column, A2 columns against the A2 pattern, and so on.  Then do something with the list of partial and full regular expressions.

The bad news is that I don't know of any software out there that implements this.

The good news is that the strategy described in http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html should be able to implement this.  In particular the `State` sets can be extended to have information about your current state in multiple patterns at the same time.  This extended set of `State` sets will result in a more complex state diagram (because you're tracking more stuff), and a more complex return at the end (you're returning a set of State sets), but runtime won't be changed a bit, whether you're matching one pattern or 50.

Comment: I can find Partial Matches, based on what I have defined in the question so it is not my major concern.

Comment: @Pranev Shah: Ah.  Then you can use regular expressions in a loop.  The more patterns you have, the slower it will run.  If that proves to be a bottleneck then you can try the strategy I suggested.  But be aware that it will be a lot of work, and for only a few patterns may be much slower than the regular expression engine is.